# CSS - Mobile Menu Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am building a menu for a responsive website - my query is what people think is the best solution for showing / hiding the menu.

I have setup the menu in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/paul_dance/5z7rvvn4/2/

The menu is hidden at 768px and a button is show - I was thinking of adding a simple js script

```
$('.menu-btn).click(function(){
  $('nav ul').slidetoggle();

});
```

or similar..

which toggles the menu on click - but my fear is if the user hides it again then expands their screen beyond 768 the menu will remain hidden and no button present to re-show.

Is there a better cross browser / device solution available?  Or a CSS only solution?  This needs to work on IE8 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using slideToggle, just toggle an `open` class on the `#nav` element.
Then in your "mobile" sized media query, have `#nav.open` display the menu (i did this by setting `#nav.open > ul` to `display:block;`).

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rally25rs/5z7rvvn4/3/

The example isnt animated, but you could add a CSS3 transition on height instead of just changing the `display:none;` of the element. CSS3 transitions wont work in IE 8 or 9, the menu will just appear, but no mobile devices run IE8 or 9, so that really shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of solutions to your problem, like this:

*instead of `slidetoggle`, use a `toggleClass`, that only works on 768px or bellow like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qkq7kcwc/1/);

*or use a css only approach with a checkbox and a label on top of your code, replacing the `button` tag with a `label` tag; when the `checkbox` will be `checked` the menu will be shown, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q6rgne8t/1/);